# Elixir app exits instead of running forever

Tags: elixir

I have coded simple elixir app, which starts websocket client and listens for incoming messages. I was expecting it to run forever. But the app exits as soon as I run it using `mix app.start`. Here is the code. What should I change to make it app run forever?

```
defmodule Example.WsClient do
  use WebSockex

  def start_link(state) do
    IO.puts "Starting WS Client"
    WebSockex.start_link("ws://example.com/ws", __MODULE__, state)
  end

  def handle_frame({type, msg}, state) do
    IO.puts "Received Message - Type: #{inspect type} -- Message: #{inspect msg}"
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_cast({:send, {type, msg} = frame}, state) do
    IO.puts "Sending #{type} frame with payload: #{msg}"
    {:reply, frame, state}
  end
end
```

```
defmodule Example.Application do
  # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html
  # for more information on OTP Applications
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      # Starts a worker by calling: Example.Worker.start_link(arg)
      {Example.WsClient, []}
    ]

    # See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html
    # for other strategies and supported options
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Example.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`mix app.start` is used for a different configuration than you need, what you need is to use either [`mix run --no-halt`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html) or `iex -S mix` (if you want to run a iex shell together with the application).